# Need a generalization of NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit to incomplete data

Tags: numerics, missing, estimation, experimental-mathematics

`` NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit `` is a great tool to obtain an empirical estimate of the limit of a sequence whose exact behavior is unknown, just from a finite prefix of the sequence. For well-behaved sequences, without erratic behavior or "gotchas", this function is often able to give a high-precision result that is close to the true value of the limit.

I need some generalization of this function. As usual, we have a finite prefix of a well-behaved convergent sequence, but it contains some "holes" — unknown values at some positions. It is not that the actual sequence has some undefined terms there, it is just that we do not have information about them, e.g. due to intermittently failing connection during data transmission, or due to a rare glitch in a numerical algorithm that resulted in an obvious outlier (e.g. a negative value when we know that all terms must be positive). We can assume the actual sequence has some finite values at those positions fitting its general observable behavior. Here is a typical example of such data:
[image: sequence]

Can we somehow get an empirical estimate of the limit of the sequence in this case (something better than if we just discarded all terms up to the last hole)?

Comment: I don't have the data that generated the plot, but why not create an interpolation and interpolate the missing values?

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about it. Unfortunately, on my data this approach return even fewer correct digits than just discarding all terms up to the last hole. Do you think there is another way that might get better precision?

Comment: Sounds like you want a monotonic interpolation method here, if you just want to fill up those missing values.

Comment: It would really help to have representative data. Absent that, perhaps try methods of the sort used for analysis of light curve data? Irregular discrete Fourier transform approaches can be employed in such settings.